# How to I write "å" on Ubuntu using an English (UK) keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

I can write `æ` and `ø` by pressing down <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd> and <kbd>o</kbd>, respectively.

However, trying all keys on my keyboard using <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>, I've not yet found a way of writing the letter `å`.

I've been looking into character codes, but by pressing down <kbd>Alt</kbd> and entering the character code 0224 etc. nothing happens.

Can someone show me how to solve the problem (I am a danish user...)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use "compose key", it is <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> (Right Alt) and then in your case <kbd>a</kbd> will produce å. You might have to press <kbd>a</kbd> twice.

[image: How to write å on English UK keyboard layout]

Comment: I tried this on English (UK) keyboard and it worked, more information in https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ComposeKey

Comment: Excellent Mike :) deleted mine + upvoted.

Comment: Thank  you, but it is weird, on my system it prints "Å", that is a capital "å" ?

Comment: Check for CAPS LOCK.

Comment: @NicolasLykkeIversen The capital Å is because you are already holding the shift key, turn caps on to get a small å, sound strange but I just tested it, in this comment

Comment: You are right, I should enable CAPS LOCK and use the steps above to get a "å". Bravo, thank you !!!

Comment: @Mike , how do you know all these tricks ?

Comment: This is not really how this works. The compose key is a sequence. You press Shift+Alt Gr on your system, and -then- the key you want to form. å is formed by either doing a and then a again, or a and then o. In this fashion you can also make the euro sign with c and then = for example. You shouldn't touch caps lock for this. Just do Shift+Alt Gr <let go> then a and a again. It's double a because of the convention to spell å as aa.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `altgr-intl` keyboard layout, <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> produces å.