# How to type Å on a German (Deutsch - Deutschland) keyboard layout - without switching to another layout

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, mint

Yes, I know there's [How to I write "å" on Ubuntu using an English (UK) keyboard?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/655960/how-to-i-write-%C3%A5-on-ubuntu-using-an-english-uk-keyboard), but I want to do the same on German (Deutsch - Deutschland) keyboard layout. I don't care if it's not a direct "typing" but rather a script that I have to assign to a keyboard combination.
Yes, I have tried `xdotool type 'Å'` and `xdotool type 'å'` but both give me the small "å" (but other "standard" letters are typed with uppercase and lowercase) and these commands don't work in Firefox at all when applied by using a keyboard combination while in Firefox (I put it on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Ü</kbd> for å and on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ü</kbd> for Å and these keyboard combinations themselves work and are unassigned - when I accidentally misspelled the command in the settings it said that there was an error executing the script because it couldn't be found).
When I issued those commands manually, coupled with a pause of one second (to give me the time to switch to Firefox) it worked with any text - but it cut out every Å and å.

Comment: Ah, I have now found the issue - it didn't like that I named the scripts for that Å.sh and å.sh although it usually accepts Äs, Ös and Üs - I changed the names to svensk-a.sh and svensk-A.sh and it works. Although the letter stays lowercase. So I removed the uppercase script, triggered the lowercase script and held down the Shift key when it appeared - and it was an uppercase Å. And I think @sudodus, your approach might work but is a bit too much work to do in the background. And I finally found the menu to install other keyboard layouts and can now easily switch between them with Super+Space.

Comment: Please don't put SOLVED in the question title. The green check mark ✅ is sufficient.

Comment: @user68186 I was (and still am) unable to see one so I thought there was no visible "Solved!" marker...

Comment: You may want to visit the [site help](https://askubuntu.com/help) and read up a bit about how this site works. This is a question answer site, and not a discussion forum and works slightly differently.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

---

*The Compose key seems to be turned off by default,

so unless you wish to enable it with "Tweak tool" (first comment below); read on here...*

---

Hit <kbd>Super</kbd> (Win-key) then type `char`
and an icon named `Characters` appears, select it / click on it.

Make sure it displays characters (a,b,c,...)
and look up the character (or symbol) you wish to enter with keys.

Click on the character;
a dialog opens showing the character and a "Code point" below it.

To make that character appear, in Firefox and mostly everywhere:

1. Hold <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd> and type <kbd>u</kbd>,
   let go of the keys (an underlined `u` should have appeared).
2. Type the code point characters; e.g. 00e5 for `å`
   *(your typing should appear underlined while you type)*
   and then press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>
   As you have pressed ENTER, the character should appear, replacing the code-point characters.

å <- this one was created by the above (00e5).
Å <- 00c5 instead, note $20 less [e ⟾ c], often so for upper case.
⅀ <- and this one (code point 2140, among Math symbols).

---

*Succesfully tried in Bash, Firefox, OpenOffice Write and Calc, ...*

```
$ . /etc/os-release && echo $NAME $VERSION
Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS (Focal Fossa)
```

---

*HTML accepts the same code points;

e.g. `&#x00e5;` will display as `å`*
*Try it at e.g. https://htmledit.squarefree.com/*

Comment: https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/tips-specialchars.html.en#compose

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+U and then typing worked (even in the application menu!) - although nothing showed up while typing, it removed the highlighted text immediately and inserted an å as soon as I pressed Enter. (I'm on Mint, which is based on Ubuntu, which might explain why nothing showed up) 
Thanks for this tip! 
It most likely works in most/all programs because it seems to be an OS function.

Comment: =) glad to help

Comment: I can verify that it works in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS (Jammy) too.